# How to tell if a second application has been added to a multi-screen?

Tags: android

On say a Samsung Galaxy S3, it's possible via an application's manifest, to allow it to run in multi-screen mode. Thus when it is running, a second application can be dragged onto the screen and each application then has half (or may be different amounts) of the screen.

When an application is running full screen, how can it tell if another application has been dragged onto the screen, and thus it now only has half of the screen real estate?

The activity is not restarted, and the onConfigurationChange method is not invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section "3-8-9. Handling Layout Changes" in this document http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs-09 gives the answer.

Note, you don't need the Samsung SDK to detect the change.